# Multiple DHCP services on Debian Jessie (systemd)

Tags: debian, systemd, services, isc-dhcpd

Since I want to add an IPv6 DHCP server (using ISC's dhcpd) additionally to run parallel to my IPv4 DHCP server on my Debian Jessie (systemd) box another instance of `dhcpd` needs to be started but this time with the `-6` parameter. I thought I would simply have a  look at the current DHCP service. So

```
# systemctl -a | grep dhcp
  isc-dhcp-server.service                     loaded    active   running   LSB: DHCP server
```

shows a something that can be found at `/run/systemd/generator.late/isc-dhcp-server.service` and is apparently a wrapper around the SysV-style script file `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server`.

So I thought I could just copy the SysV script, adapt it (replace every occurrence of  `dhcp` with `dhcp6` except for the binary name) and then also copy the `/run/systemd/generator.late/isc-dhcp-server.service` and adapt it to point to the new script and that's it but apparently I wasn't successful because `systemctl -a | grep dhcp6` yields no results.

Also:

```
# sudo systemctl enable dhcp6.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I could've made wrong? Or how I could debug what I made wrong? Or is there any more comfortable and maybe less hackish way to clone a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be quite honest, what I'd recommend here would be to ignore the SysV script altogether, and just create your own systemd script. I'm actually considering doing that for isc-dhcp-server, due to some annoying situations in which I mess stuff up and systemd doesn't even notice; it'd be a lot easier to deal with (particularly under script control) if the death of the daemon resulted in the service changing status.

Comment: I simply gave up on IPv6 DHCP then anyway for a different reason but I feel like your answer basically sums up nicely what probably the best approach would be.

Comment: FWIW I'm hoping that a lot of these will be resolved once Debian Stretch is released; with systemd becoming the default, I would expect that proper systemd service files will be created for most key packages. That would deal with a lot of the problems.